# Unable to select option again with input group

Tags: reactjs, select, input, antd

I use antd for selecting group of options

```
import { Input, Select } from 'antd';

...

const InputGroup = Input.Group;
const Option = Select.Option;

...

<InputGroup size="large">
  <Select style={{ width: 100 }} placeholder="MR">
    <Option value="MR">MR</Option>
    <Option value="MS">MS</Option>
  </Select>
</InputGroup>
```

[image]

after select 1 option, I unable to select again, I can not select anywhere. There is an overlapping div appeared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Antd documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/) you need to make use of `defaultValue` on the `<Select>` tag

So in your case it will be :

```
  <Select defaultValue="MR" style={{ width: 100 }}>
    <Option value="MR">MR</Option>
    <Option value="MS">MS</Option>
  </Select>
```

Comment: There is a dropdown that overlap screen.

Comment: Is there a problem with dropdown overlapping screen or you can’t select options again ? Can you post a link to repo etc

Comment: I add a picture for that dropdown. Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: I have set defaultValue to one of the values from Option and remove the placeholder,  further please specify the width is it `100%` ? if that does not work then try without  `style` property , As thats the only thing I can find in documentation